# Proving that in a simple graph with $n$ vertices, two vertices have the same degree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

I want to prove this claim using contradiction:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices. Prove by contradiction that $G$ has two vertices having the same degree (Consider the vertex of smallest degree and vertex of largest degree).

I think I know where to start. The vertex of the largest degree is $n-1$ in this graph and the smallest is 1. How can I use contradiction to prove the statement above? I studied the proof of this using pigeonhole but I wanna use contradiction this time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose such a graph exists. Each vertex in the graph can have a degree from $0$ to $n-1$ (simple graphs do not forbid a degree-$0$ vertex, *connected* graphs do). Since this range spans $n$ values in total and each vertex degree is different, the degrees are distributed one-per-vertex. In particular, there must exist a vertex with degree $n-1$ and one with degree $0$.

Now the degree-$n-1$ vertex is connected to all other vertices because the graph is simple, *including* the degree-$0$ vertex. But the latter is not connected to any vertex, which is a contradiction. Therefore two vertices in the graph must have the same degree.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Comment: "Since this range spans  values in total and each vertex degree is different, the degrees are distributed one-per-vertex." Why is that the case? Could you clarify that? Great answer by the way

Comment: ^ similar question on this sentence too. +1 for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a graph $G$ where all vertices have distinct degrees. So, $$d(1)<d(2)<\cdots<d(n),$$
and $$d(1)>0, d(2)>d(1)>0, \ldots, d(n)>d(n-1)>\ldots>0.$$

Hence we have just one vertex of degree $\geq n-1$.

However, in a simple graph with $n$ vertices a vertex can have a maximum degree of $n-1$. So, $d(n)=d(n-1)$. So, our assumption of having all degrees different was wrong and we have a contradiction.

So, in a simple graph $G$, we must have at least $2$ vertices of the same degree.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please format you post using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: I'm confused about why you have $d(1)>0$. Could you explain further?

Comment: We are showing that we want two vertices of the same degree. So, why would we bother to have d(1) = 0 if we are in a simple graph? I think we can just say that we are considering graphs with at least one edge because in a graph of just one vertex this will never apply.

Comment: There are graphs with at least one edge that also have isolated vertices: for example, consider the graph  $•\phantom{==} •—•—• \phantom{==} • \phantom{==} •—•$. So you cannot just omit the 0-degree case.